# Passing two parameters (int and array) to embedded Python function

Tags: python, c, python-c-api, python-embedding

I need to call Python function from my module and set two parameters for it: int and array.

For a now I get segfault during calling this function and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Could someone specify where my mistake is?

Function in my Python module app.py. It works if I call it from Python code:

```
def get_model(rate, signal):
    mfcc_train = MFCC().compute(rate, signal) 
    with open('mfcc_test', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(mfcc_train, f)
    return clf()._fit(mfcc_train)
```

My C code that calls the function above. The last pring is "Before calling"

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "wav.h"
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pValue, *pArgs;
    uint8_t *samples = NULL;

    wavread("test.wav", &samples);

    printf("No. of channels: %d\n",     header->num_channels);
    printf("Sample rate:     %d\n",     header->sample_rate);
    printf("Bit rate:        %dkbps\n", header->byte_rate*8 / 1000);
    printf("Bits per sample: %d\n\n",     header->bps);
    printf("Sample 0:        %d\n", samples[0]);
    printf("Sample 1:        %d\n", samples[1]);
    // Initialize the Python Interpreter
    printf("Before init\n");
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject *sysPath = PySys_GetObject("path");
    const char *scriptDirectoryName = ".";
    PyObject *path = PyUnicode_FromString(scriptDirectoryName);
    int result = PyList_Insert(sysPath, 0, path);
    printf("after init\n");
    // Build the name object
    pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault(argv[1]);
    printf("after pname %s %d\n", argv[1], pName == NULL ? 1 : 0);

    // Load the module object
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    printf("after pmodule %d\n", pModule == NULL ? 1 : 0);

    // pFunc is also a borrowed reference 
    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "get_model");
    printf("after pfunc\n");

    if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) 
    {
        pArgs = PyTuple_New(2);
        printf("after pytuple\n");
        PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, PyLong_FromLong(header->sample_rate));
        printf("after set item\n");
        uint8_t* array = malloc(header->datachunk_size);
        int dims[1];
        dims[0] = header->datachunk_size;
        printf("alloc\n");
        import_array();
        PyObject* pSamples = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dims, NPY_INT8, (void*)samples);
        printf("pSamples\n");
        PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS((PyArrayObject*)pSamples, NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA);
        PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, pSamples);
        printf("Before calling\n");
        pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
        printf("After calling\n");
    } else 
    {
        PyErr_Print();
    }

    printf("pValue:        %d\n", pValue);
    // Clean up
    Py_DECREF(pModule);
    Py_DECREF(pFunc);
    Py_DECREF(pName);

    // Finish the Python Interpreter
    Py_Finalize();

    free(header);
    free(samples);
}
```

**UPD:** updated code where one issue was fixed. But another problem still exists. It's in line `PyObject* pSamples = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dims, NPY_INT8, (void*)samples);`. And I can't find out what is wrong with it.

And wav.h just in case:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <err.h>
typedef struct {
    char     chunk_id[4];
    uint32_t chunk_size;
    char     format[4];
    char     fmtchunk_id[4];
    uint32_t fmtchunk_size;
    uint16_t audio_format;
    uint16_t num_channels;
    uint32_t sample_rate;
    uint32_t byte_rate;
    uint16_t block_align;
    uint16_t bps;
    char     datachunk_id[4];
    uint32_t datachunk_size;
}WavHeader;
WavHeader *header;
void wavread(char *file_name, int16_t **samples)
{
    int fd;
    if (!file_name)
        errx(1, "Filename not specified");
    if ((fd = open(file_name, O_RDONLY)) < 1)
        errx(1, "Error opening file");
    if (!header)
        header = (WavHeader*)malloc(sizeof(WavHeader));
    if (read(fd, header, sizeof(WavHeader)) < sizeof(WavHeader))
        errx(1, "File broken: header");
    if (strncmp(header->chunk_id, "RIFF", 4) ||
        strncmp(header->format, "WAVE", 4))
        errx(1, "Not a wav file");
    if (header->audio_format != 1)
        errx(1, "Only PCM encoding supported");
    if (*samples) free(*samples);
    *samples = (int16_t*)malloc(header->datachunk_size);
    if (!*samples)
        errx(1, "Error allocating memory");
    if (read(fd, *samples, header->datachunk_size) < header->datachunk_size)
        errx(1, "File broken: samples");
    close(fd);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to tell without the definition of `header` but I believe the issue is in the line

```
PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, header->sample_rate);
```

`PyTuple_SetItem` expects a Python object and you're passing it what I think is an integer, which is being misinterpreted as a `PyObject*`.

I suspect you want

```
PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, PyInt_FromLong(header->sample_rate));
```

(`PyLong_FromLong` in Python3)

---

Second issue: you `free` `samples` twice. First you pass it to numpy and tell numpy that it owns the data:

```
PyObject* pSamples = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dims, NPY_INT8, (void*)samples);
PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS((PyArrayObject*)pSamples, NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA);
```

then at the end of your code you free it

```
free(samples);
```

I suspect that you meant to pass your newly allocated `array` to numpy instead of `samples`. (You still need to copy the data between them too, if this is the case)

**UPD:** One more right solution from comments is to change type of dims from int to npy_intp

Comment: Yes, you're right. I forgot to update this post yesterday when I found out this issue. But unfortunately this is not only problem in my code.

Now I have trouble with this line: `PyObject* pSamples = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dims, NPY_INT8, (void*)samples);` It works but not in right way because sometime I got segfault at the end of execution and some another side effects.

Comment: And don't mind about the header wav.h. It's just for reading wav file. But just in case I added it to post.

Comment: Thank you, now I recognized that I don't need last `free` call. But my main issue is not connected with this. I get segfault every second time during `PyObject_CallObject`. And I don't understand what you mean in last sentence. I put wrapper pSamples into arguments. And it already contains necessary data, doesn't it?

Comment: The last line was guessing that you do `uint8_t* array = malloc(header->datachunk_size);` with the intention of passing it to numpy instead of `samples` (in which case you'd need to copy the data). I could be guessing wrongly though

Comment: I'm struggling to see anything else obviously wrong right now I'm afraid. Two small suggestions: 1) make `dims` a `npy_intp` just to check that you haven't got an integer type mismatch. 2) Most of your Python functions return `NULL` if there's an error - add checks after each one for that

Comment: Now I see. No, `array` is rudiment. I forgot to delete this line.
Got it. I will do all that you advised me. But I'm afraid I could do it nor earlier than on Monday. I will share results. Thank you one more time!

Comment: You were right - the problem was in wront type of dims. With npy_intp it works almost perfect! "Almost" because one time from about thirty runs I got segfault. But I can't reproduce it.
Thank you very much!